# Is there a way to have my main web page change at a certain date/time?

Tags: html

I'm doing a project for school, and I think my idea is bigger than my capabilities as of now. I'm wanting my homepage to display information from another page on certain days. For example, I would want it to display certain items on Mon/Thurs/Sun, and others on Tues/Fri, etc. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript to check the date and load/redirect your page to the desired ones. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide It is highly advisable that you have some notion of computer programming, even a basic one.

Comment: Besides the already mentioned MDN docs I found [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/)  to be a really good resource for learning the basics and looking stuff up

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.